# Different handlers for same path but different query params

Tags: python, flask

I have a single URL, GET /journal, but I need to handle two different set of query params in Flask.

```
GET /journal?start_date=<start_date>&end_date=<end_date>
GET /journal?offset=<offset>&limit=<limit>
```

I want the handlers to be as follows:

```
  @bp.route('/journal', methods=['GET'])
  def get_journals_date_range(start_date, end_date):
    # handle request
    pass

  @bp.route('/journal', methods=['GET'])
  def get_paginated(offset, limit):
    # handle request
    pass
```

How can I implement this in Flask Python?

I am not sure how to handle this and any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Skipping all the talks on if this is the best approach from the "best practices", "standards" and whatnots point of view ...
If the framework allows it I'd try creating a method with all the parameters, make them optional and call the desired method (range or paginated) according to the input

```
  @bp.route('/journal', methods=['GET'])
  def get_journals(start_date=None, end_date=None, offset=None, limit=None):
    # depending from what's the desired behavior you could/shoul replace the "and"s with "or"s 
    if start_date is not None and end_date is not None: 
      return get_journals_date_range(start_date, end_date)
    elif offset is not None and offset is not None:
      return get_journals_paginated(offset, limit)
    else:
      pass
      # do something ... make it  raise an error or return an HTTP 400, or choose a default behavior that calls one of those methods
 
  def get_journals_date_range(start_date, end_date):
    # handle request
    pass

  def get_journals_paginated(offset, limit):
    # handle request
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to request query parameters, flask offers the possibility with `request.args`. Here the variant including standard value and type change to int.

```py
offset = request.args.get('offset', 0, type=int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do it that way.

You need a single route, and then you would handle the query parameters inside the route.

```
@bp.route('/journal', methods=['GET'])
def get_journal():
    if 'start_date' in request.args and 'end_date' in request.args:
        # handle date ranges

    elif 'offset' in request.args and 'limit' in request.args:
        # handle pagination
```